# Transpose unique columns to duplicate rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, dax

Does anyone know how to create this type of matrix (as shown in the figure)? Basically, transpose 'row values' to 'column', with respect to its data value.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to find the first cell containing non-zero value, paste this in A2 and drag it down:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$F$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B2:F2<>0,0),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to generate the numbers in column A, for this example, is

```
=MATCH("",B2:F2,-1)
```

This finds the last non-empty string in the range `B2:F2`.

It's shorter than Mahesh's formula, but less generalizable as it doesn't read the values in Row 1.